# How to design a common source amplifier with inductive load?

Tags: power, amplifier, analog

If I want to design a common source amplifier with inductive load (L as the RF choke), how can I choose the values L, C, and W of the transistor? Given the following parameters:

Vdd = 1V

Vout peak swing = 2V

R = 50 ohm

Vin 1GHz, 0.1V peak

Vth = 0.5V

Power delivered to the load = 1W

Why Vx can be larger than Vdd?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: "Why Vx can be larger than Vdd?" Because the DC point at Vx = Vdd, and the AC peak voltage (transistor fully on) also = VDD. Therefore the peak to peak voltage will be 2*Vdd.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Then how can we determine the values of L and C and the width of the transistor?

Comment: Generally, XL should be much higher than R at frequency F. XC should be much lower. Other considerations specific to the design will impose other constraints : I have no idea what your design considerations are.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Thanks. So 1/wC << R is required because we want the AC voltage at Vx to pass through the capacitor. And wL >> R is required because we want to block the AC voltage from passing through the inductor to reach Vx. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: I have a follow-up question. I also want to know the gain of such an amplifier. If the load is resistive, the gain is gm*Rd. But it is an inductive load. So is the Rd in this case realized by the parasitic resistance in parallel with the inductor?

Comment: No, don't be fooled by the high inductor impedance or the parasitics. To a first order approximation. the load is R. (A better approx is (R + Xc) in parallel with XL.